# Chamberlain 045ACT Opener Button

Tags: garage

I have a Chamberlain 045ACT garage door opener.  It has a wired push button for opening and closing the door. I want to add a second button, so I can open and close it from two different places.  How do I do this? Have you tested to verify it works?

Answer (score 1):

The pushbutton is an N.O. (normally open) switch.  When you press it, the circuit is closed and the opener starts its cycle.  It's easy to add a 2nd pushbutton by wiring it in PARALLEL to the first one.  That way EITHER one, acting alone can control the door.

For a diagram of this see the 'Switches in Parallel' diagram at:

[Switches In Parallel](https://electronicsclub.info/seriesparallel.htm)